# Magento 2 MEQP2 WARNING | The use of function file_get_contents() is discouraged

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, meqp2

I am getting **WARNING** | The use of **function file_get_contents()** is discouraged. but its working fine but not for **MEQP2** its giving WARNING so how use **alternate** of function `file_get_contents()` in the code.

```
public function importFromTranslationFile($filePath)
{
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
    if ($fileContent !== false) {
        $fileContent = trim($fileContent, '`');

        return json_decode($fileContent, true);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Interfaces available inside `Magento\Framework`.

There are classes to help you, for example `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface` gives you access to a `fileGetContents` function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve file contents from given path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string|null $flag
 * @param resource|null $context
 * @return string
 * @throws FileSystemException
 */
public function fileGetContents($path, $flag = null, $context = null);
```

Which is implemented inside `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver`

```
/**
 * Retrieve file contents from given path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string|null $flag
 * @param resource|null $context
 * @return string
 * @throws FileSystemException
 */
public function fileGetContents($path, $flag = null, $context = null)
{
    clearstatcache();
    $result = @file_get_contents($this->getScheme() . $path, $flag, $context);
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new FileSystemException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                'Cannot read contents from file "%1" %2',
                [$path, $this->getWarningMessage()]
            )
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This is going to be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it'll ignore from MEQP testing

```
public function importFromTranslationFile($filePath)
    {
        //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
        //@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
        if ($fileContent !== false) {
            $fileContent = trim($fileContent, '');
            return json_decode($fileContent, true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will submit my extension in Magento marketplace. is this method allow in MMP QA.

Comment: Yes, **@MRIZWAN** for some reason you have to use some function then you can use it but not for each and every warnings.